# Objects within an Array, to be referenced later

Tags: javascript

I want to place all the hmAttKeys under one type of hmFeeTypeAttKey so that when I later reference hmAttKeys, it comes out individually but I am not sure of the right sytax. I also tried `hmFeeTypeAttKey[0] = [13,3,11,12]`. Any suggestions?

```
hmAttKeys=[]
hmAttKeys[13]="/red";
hmAttKeys[3]="/blue";
hmAttKeys[11]="/green";
hmAttKeys[12]="/yellow";

var hmFeeTypeAttKey = [];
hmFeeTypeAttKey[0] = [13][3][11][12]; 

hmAttKeys[hmFeeTypeIndex[0]]
```

Comment: `hmFeeTypeAttKey[0] = [hmAttKeys[13],hmAttKeys[3],....]; `

Comment: (though , saving indexes is better)

Answer (score 0):

```
hmAttKeys=[]
hmAttKeys[13]="/red";
hmAttKeys[3]="/blue";
hmAttKeys[11]="/green";
hmAttKeys[12]="/yellow";    
i=0;
var hmFeeTypeAttKey = [];
for( key in hmAttKeys )
{
hmFeeTypeAttKey[i]=key;
i++;
}
```

now you can loop through the array to get the keys back for reference..

```
for(var j=0;j<hmfeeTypeAttKey.length;j++)
{
console.log(hmAttKeys[hmfeeTypeAttKey[j]])
}
```